# ActivatedRoute subscribe not triggering in child component

Tags: angular, angular-routing

let's consider the following routing :

```
 path: 'requests/:id', component: PublicationsRequestDetailComponent, resolve: { request: PublicationsRequestDetailResolverService },
            runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
            children: [
                 {
                    path: 'summary', component: PublicationsRequestSummaryComponent
                },
```

If I do this in the PublicationsRequestDetailComponent :

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
   this._route.params.subscribe(m => {
  console.log(m);
 });
}
```

I can read the id parameter passed in the route (m = {id: 'some value'})

however, the same code inside the PublicationsRequestSummaryComponent gives me m = {}

So in the child component, the route params is an empty object.

Why is that ? How can detect route changes from my child component ?

Answer (score 0):

A) You should put an Id in the child path as well, shouldn't?

```
...
children: [
                 {
                    path: 'summary/:id', 
                    component: PublicationsRequestSummaryComponent
                },
...
```

B) Besides, I guess there is another way to get the rute id parameter, in this way:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
  }
```

You could test both solutions, first the A), then B), and finally A+B together.

Comment: when you reach the child path, the route is `requests/id/summary`, no `requests/summary/id`. So, no I shouldn't have the id in the childpath. But I'm wondering if this is the problem. My route is valid, so is there a way to subscribe to the route change ?  What you describe in B) wouldn't work. What I want is to take action whenever the parameter in the route changes, which is not the purpose of snapshot.

Comment: ok, I see... I'm wondering too if a rute like **requests/id/summary** is valid in the front. Sometimes I use routes in that way for the *endpoints* in the API/BACK, but I never used a route like this in the front, always are like **requests/summary/id**. But I don't know whether or not they are possible that way in the front... I'll stick around to see if someone says something about it. Regarding subscribing to route changes, yes, I agree, option B would not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

ok, the fix was to use route.parent

```
 this._route.parent.params.subscribe(m => {
    console.log(m);
 });
```